# How to use wkHtmltoPdf to generate PDf files from statcic html files in JS

Tags: javascript

Can anyone suggest how to use wkhtmltopdf in JS to generate PDF files from static html files?

wkhtmltopdf - http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

All answers say run "wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com google.pdf"

But run the code where? On a server? On a browser? On a command line?

Any code samples will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the project's homepage](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/index.html): it's a command line tool.

> ### What is it?
>
> **wkhtmltopdf** and **wkhtmltoimage** are open source (LGPL) command line tools to render HTML into PDF and various image formats using the QT Webkit rendering engine. These run entirely "headless" and do not require a display or display service.

In your server-side application, you can call the binary and wait for its output (for PHP, it's basically `$output = exec("wkhtmltopdf $url $options");`). There used to be an example wrapper on the project's Google Code wiki, but it seems to be gone.

If you're using PHP and don't want to write a wrapper yourself then you can use [this one](https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf). If there's no wrapper for your chosen server-side language, then try making one yourself. It's not hard.

Your front-end JavaScript will have to call (probably using AJAX) a script that runs on your server to generate the PDF.

Comment: Hey i am not using PHP. Can u please suggest somethng specific to JS, HTML and CSS? thanks a lot

Comment: Impossible. You need a server side language. That can be JavaScript via node.js, but you can't use wkhtmltopdf without a server side component.